# Count the number of words that start with ‘S’ in input_list

Tags: python, list, map-function

I want to count the number of words by making use of only the map function along with the lambda function

Here is the code which I have written

```py
input_list = ['San Jose', 'San Francisco', 'Santa Fe', 'Houston']
len(list(map(lambda word:word if word[0]=="S",input_list)))
```

However, this is throwing an error like so

```
File "/code/source.py3", line 5
    count = len(list(map(lambda word:word if word[0]=="S",input_list)))
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `filter()`?

Comment: No, actually the question does not allow me to use filter

Comment: You're using the lambda incorrectly. `word if word[0]=="S"` needs an `else` to tell it what to return if the condition isn't true, but it seems like you're trying to use it as if it were a condition in a list comprehension.

Comment: But `map()` is not suitable. It is used to transform one iterable into another of the same length. Whereas `filter()` is used to select a subset from the input iterable.

Comment: The usual way to do it would be `len([word for word in input_list if word[0]=="S"])`. Neither map nor lambda are useful there.

Comment: @Kemp but the question asks me to use map function only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using `map()` then using `sum()` might work:

```py
input_list = ['San Jose', 'San Francisco', 'Santa Fe', 'Houston']
count = sum(map(lambda word:word[0]=="S", input_list))
```

Note that `word[0]=="S"` evaluates to `True` or `False`, which when used with `sum()` is translated to `1` or `0` resp.

Comment: @python_user: Ok, yes, that's an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

```
len([x for x in input_list if x.startswith('S')])
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do this
`sum(map(lambda x:x.startswith("S"), input_list))`